# Pulling Data from a Mysql Table Field and putting it into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I can find lots of tutorials showing you how to load an array into a database field but can't seem to figure out how to pull each entry in a field into an array as seperate items.  Seems simple enough just can't get it to work, any help?

Comment: can you clarify exactly what you want, because there's clearly some confusion in the answers.  My interpretation is that you'd like all of the values from _one_ field extracted from _many_ rows to appear as an array.

Answer (score 1):

If using the modern PDO library, use the [`PDOStatement->fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function with the `fetch_style` parameter set to `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`.

Based on a sample from that page:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT field FROM dbtable");
$sth->execute();
$array = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

If using the old MySQL API (not recommended, example omits error checking)

```
$array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT field FROM dbtable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
     $array[] = $row[0];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$big_2_dimensional_array_of_data;

foreach ($big_array_of_data as $row) {
  $query = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, ...) VALUES($row[0], $row[1], ...)
  mysql_query($query);
}
```

Something like that I think

Comment: wrong way around - I believe he wants to SELECT data, not INSERT it.

Answer (score 0):

after reading his question a few times, i guess what he wants to do is something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT field1, field2, ... fieldn FROM table;";
$r = mysql_query($query,$conn);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
```

i'm still not quite sure what it is he exactly wants...

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this question is that the questioner has inserted a number of rows into a table, and isn't sure how to handle getting them out other than one at a time.  (It's possible that the question might also be referring to data serialized and then stuck into a single field... but I hope not!)

So, here's how to get multiple rows:

```
$query = "SELECT field1, field2, ... fieldn FROM table;";
$r = mysql_query($query,$conn);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

You'd now have all the rows returned by your query in `$data`, so something like this would work to access it: `$data[2]['field1']`

Answer (score 0):

The examples below assume your `SELECT` statement is stored in `$select` and your connection is stored in `$db`.  A two-dimensional array of the results is stored in `$rows` afterward.

If you're using `mysql` (for `mysqli` procedures, just replace `mysql_` with `mysqli_`):

```
$result = mysql_query($select, $db);

$rows = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Using `mysqli` classes:

```
$result = $db->query($select);

$rows = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$result->close()
```

Using `PDO`:

```
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```